# How can a single button load pages into an iframe in sequence?

Tags: javascript

On load, another script loads a file into the iframe. The file is named abcdX.html where X is a number and it is in the same directory as this page. If abcd1.html is loaded in the iframe, pressing a button should load abcd2.html, then abcd3.html, etc.

I have tried this, but the button does nothing:

```
<html>

<head>
    <script>
    turnRight = function() {

        var srcurl = document.getElementByName("content").src.charAt(4);
        var pagenum = parseInt(srcurl, 10) + 1;

        if (pagenum < 4) {
            document.getElementByName('content').src='abcd' + pagenum + '.html';
        }
        else {
            pagenum = 1;
            document.getElementByName('content').src='abcd' + pagenum + '.html';
        }

    };  
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div onclick="turnRight()"></div>
    <iframe name="content" id="content">
</body>

</html>
```

edit: using Jan's suggestion, my original code, and another stack thread, I constructed this, and it works as defined, including the url reading:

```
let turnRight = function() {
    var frameUrl = document.getElementById('content').contentWindow.location.href;
    var cutoff = frameUrl.substr(frameUrl.length - 6);
    var pageNumber = parseInt(cutoff.charAt(0), 10);
    var maxPageNumber = 4;
    pageNumber = (pageNumber % maxPageNumber) + 1;
    document.getElementById('content').src = 'abcd' + pageNumber + '.html';
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `getElementByName` does not exist by default. You can change `getElementByName` to `getElementById` to query the iframe-object. It's also not a the best idea to get the current page-number from the src of the iframe, because the position/index of that information can vary. You can keep track of the current pagenumber in an extra variable. You also don't need an if-else block to reset the pagenumber once it reaches the maximum, this can be achieved with modulo.

Here is an example with the mentioned changes to your original code:

```
let pageNumber = 0;
let maxPageNumber = 4;
let turnRight = function() {
    pageNumber = (pageNumber % maxPageNumber) + 1;
    document.getElementById("content").src = 'abcd' + pageNumber + '.html';
};
```

Comment: Thanks, with this I fixed it and updated my post. I found a way to get the current number from the url by cutting off its last 6 chars first (#.html), that way the actual path doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

I would keep a variable outside the turnRight function that will save the current count, starting at 1. Then when you click the button, add 1 to the counting variable and load the correct url into the iFrame.

Made an example:

```js
var count = 1;
var baseUrl = 'abcd#.html';

var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
var button = document.querySelector('.button');

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    count++;
    
    if (count > 4) {
        count = 1;
    }
    
    iframe.src = baseUrl.replace('#', count);
});
```

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
    <button type="button" class="button">Click!</button>
    <iframe name="content" id="content">
</body>

</html>
```